# Mi servidor IIS muestra la pagina hasta que la carga por completo evitando mostrar la animación de carga

Tags: javascript, php, css, animación, wamp

Disculpen, uso wamp en mi pc para desarrollar y mi servidor local donde corre todo es iis, el problema que tengo es que hice una animación para mostrar mientras carga una pagina que requiere muchas consultas, en mi pc con wamp funciona muy bien pero en iis se muestra la pagina hasta que ya se cargo por ende ya no se muestra la animación, esto genera mucho tiempo en que el usuario no sabe si realmente esta cargando o no.

¿Hay alguna configuración en iis que tengo desactivada que evita que se muestre la pagina hasta que esta completamente cargada?

Este es el link del servidor, como verán aquí se muestra hasta que se despacho todo y eso evita que se muestre la animación: https://ec49-201-121-91-22.ngrok.io/pruevas/prueva.php

Este es el link a mi wamp de desarrollo, así quisiera que se muestre la pagina cargando y la animación: https://b1e2-201-121-105-1.ngrok.io/kenal/pruevas/prueva.php

Les agradezco mucho su apoyo y todos sus comentarios!
Nota, todo en este caso es en PHP.

Comment: Estás 100% seguro que el IIS es en realidad el problema? Antes de ponerse a jugar con las configuraciones del IIS, te recomiendo pongas algunos `console.log` y `alert`s para conocer cuál es el orden de carga de tus archivos js. Sabes en qué momento se disparan los xhr request? Sabes si es asíncrono? No digo que no sea el IIS, pero, ya descartaste por completo tu sitio web?

Comment: Segun el analizador de red, lo que más tarda es tu PHP, unos 26 segundos!!  No se que haces en el PHP, pero eso es lo que debes depurar primero, pues si no llega a cargarse no envia los datos ni la animacion durante ese tiempo

Comment: En cambio, desde tu apache en windows tu php tarda menos de 1 segundo, y por eso tienes la sensación que va mejor, claro, pues ya ha cargado la página y la animación se lanza antes (y no 26 segundos mas tarde)

Comment: agradezco sus comentarios, es que son el mismo desarrollo, exacto e igual, acabo de actualizar la información de las tablas para que carguen las mismas consultas a Mysql ambos, es lo que no entiendo porque mi wamp carga por partes, es decir va apareciendo las tablas poco a poco y por ende aparece la animacion de carga, en cambio en iis no carga nada hasta que ha terminado de calcular, pero si reitero que ambas paginas que puse arriba son exactamente la misma solo una se ejecuta en mi wamp y otra en iis, gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Podría ser una configuración de IIS / PHP donde se activa un búfer de salida. Revisa [este enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8a3fa78-6641-4e0d-9e99-b31d88bfbc32/output-buffering-in-php-in-iis-85?forum=iisfastcgimodule) a ver si te sirve de algo. Aunque, como ya te dijeron, también hay que revisar porqué PHP tarda tanto en ejecutarse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas gracias @Triby en tu comentario me dejaste un enlace, aqui explican como cambiar PHP_via_FastCGI.responseBufferLimit el cual tenia configurado en 4194304, al cambiarlo a 0 la respuesta es la esperada, dejo el link de la pregunta donde explican como resolverlo, la segunda respuesta fue la que me ayudo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315815/php-flush-stopped-flushing-in-iis-8

Abri cmd y ejecute:

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list config
> -section:system.webServer/handlers | find "FastCGI"

Luego ejecute

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config
> -section:system.webServer/handlers /[name='PHP53_via_FastCGI'].responseBufferLimit:"0" /commit:apphost

cambiando **PHP53_via_FastCGI** por mi version, en este caso **PHP_via_FastCGI**

y listo. gracias a todos los que dedicaron su tiempo.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte también!  En 48 horas podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta y así ayudar a los que vengan aquí con tu mismo problema.